# Linq Query Filed

Tags: c#, linq, wcf

I am to get List user by using Linq query. I have local to encrypt the user password but when initialized local class filed to entity model class field, it's showing the following error ...

```
 cannot convert from 'HalifaxWCFProject.PasswordEncrypt.UserLogin' to 'HalifaxWCFProject.HalifaxDatabaseEntities'   HalifaxWCFProjet
```

Here is my Local Class.

```
 [DataContract]
    public class UserLogin
    {
        string id;
        string username;
        string password;
        string email;


        [DataMember]
        public string Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Username
        {
            get { return username; }
            set { username = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Password
        {
            get { return password; }
            set { password = value; }


        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set { email = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Method ..

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
UriTemplate = "/GetAllStudent/")]
List<UserLogin> GetAllStudent();
```

Here is Implementation of the method .

```
  public List<UserLogin> GetAllStudent()
        {

            var query = (from a in ctx.tblUsers
                         select a).Distinct();

            List<HalifaxDatabaseEntities> userList = new List<HalifaxDatabaseEntities>();

            query.ToList().ForEach(rec =>
            {
                userList.Add( new UserLogin
                {
                    Id =Convert.ToString(rec.Id),
                    Username = rec.Username,
                   Password = rec.Password,//Error on this line

                Email = rec.Email

                });
            });
            return userList;
        }

    }
```

What is the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you make `userList` a `List<UserLogin>`?

Comment: @juharr given the question, I'd say it's either inherited or copy-pasted from somewhere...

Comment: List<UserLogin> because I am returning List of User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrectly declared your variable type for the `userList` variable. Make life easier (and your code more readable) by just using the `var` keyword.

However, better yet for readability reasons, use a `Select` to create your new types.

```
var query = (from a in ctx.tblUsers select a).Distinct();
var result = query.Select(rec => new UserLogin
{
    Id = Convert.ToString(rec.Id),
    Username = rec.Username,
    Password = rec.Password,
    Email = rec.Email
});
return result.ToList();
```

You could collapse it further too if you want by not even bothering with the `query` and `result` variables.

Also, the `Distinct` seems like it wouldn't make a difference here since you're already selecting from a single table.

Comment: Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
            List<HalifaxDatabaseEntities> userList = new List<HalifaxDatabaseEntities>();
```

needs to be:

```
        List<UserLogin> userList = new List<UserLogin>();
```